# Horizontal scroll bar on code tags overlaps the last line

Tags: bug, status-norepro, css

I noticed that on `Google Chrome 46.0.2490.71` on `Win 7x64` the last line in a code block overlaps the horizontal scroll bar.

For eg(From the time travel question):

```
from datetime import*
o=0
while 1:n=datetime.now();o=o or n;print"%s;%s: %s? You mean we're in the future?"%(o,n,n.year)if(n-o).days>=1else"%s;%s: Back in good old %s."%(n,o,n.year)if(n<o)else"Great Scott!";o=n
```

A `padding-bottom:15px;`  on the `<pre>` tag generated seems to work well in this case.

[image: work well]

I guess this is because Chrome now uses internal scroll bars instead of external.

Comment: Looks fine without style changes with that identical version of Chrome on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome on Windows 7, too.

Comment: Ah! found the issue. I had enabled `Overlay Scrollbars` in the experimental flags.